# ../bootstrap/scss/_normalize not found

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I'm upgrading from Webpack 2 to 4 (Vue). I have deleted my config files and used Webpack-CLI 3 to generate new config files. But it's generating a few errors, and and one that I cannot understand is:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: ../bootstrap/scss/_normalize.
```

What does that mean? Thanks.

Comment: Can you see normalize  module in node_modules folder ?

Comment: @TonyNgo ack brings up five folders named normalize but none of them are just called normalize. They're called normalize-package-data, normalize-path, normalize-range and normalize-url. ak -i _normalize also brings nothing. What should I do? Is there a module named normalize I'm not unaware of? But it says _normalize is a bootstrap file... So which is it?